# Groovy Pretty Print XML assertion fails

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm writing a unit test that verify if the xml is formatted correctly, but this is failing and I can't figure out why.

So I decided to test the code of [this blog post](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.br/2012/10/groovy-goodness-pretty-print-xml.html) and test in the Grails console, it also fails.

```
import groovy.xml.*

def prettyXml = '''\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<languages>
  <language id="1">Groovy</language>
  <language id="2">Java</language>
  <language id="3">Scala</language>
</languages>
'''


// Pretty print a non-formatted XML String.
def xmlString = '<languages><language id="1">Groovy</language><language id="2">Java</language><language id="3">Scala</language></languages>'
assert XmlUtil.serialize(xmlString) == prettyXml
```

Assertion fails with:

```
Assertion failed: 

assert XmlUtil.serialize(xmlString) == prettyXml
               |         |          |  |
               |         |          |  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
               |         |          |  <languages>
               |         |          |    <language id="1">Groovy</language>
               |         |          |    <language id="2">Java</language>
               |         |          |    <language id="3">Scala</language>
               |         |          |  </languages>
               |         |          false
               |         <languages><language id="1">Groovy</language><language id="2">Java</language><language id="3">Scala</language></languages>
               <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
               <languages>
                 <language id="1">Groovy</language>
                 <language id="2">Java</language>
                 <language id="3">Scala</language>
               </languages>
```

I'm using Grails 2.2.1, that uses Groovy 2.0.7, on Windows 7.

Maybe is something related with the OS line separator?

**EDIT**

I saved both strings to file, and checked with Notepad++

The parsed xml (XmlUtils) have `CL+RF` as line separator but the `prettyXml` have only `LF`. I also tested using `\n` instead of a multi line declaration, with same result!

Groovy shouldn't use `CL+RF` always, since this is the Windows line separator?

Comment: What about opening both versions in a hex editor to check for weird EOL bytes and stuff?

Comment: [Maybe try xmlunit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727876/comparing-two-xml-strings-files-in-groovy-java)?

Comment: @WillP Good catch. Sometimes you spent a lot of time seeing something that your brain stop working hehe. Check my update

Comment: @tim_yates Thanks, XMLUnit returns them as equals. I'm just puzzled why the line separator is different.

Comment: In the end, I just used:

XmlUtil.serialize(writer).replaceAll("\r", "")

Answer (score 0):

In the [Groovy String/GString docs](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Strings+and+GString), it says in relation to multi-line literals:

> There[sic] are always represented by the character '\n', regardless of
>   the line-termination conventions of the host system.

They don't really say why, unfortunately.