# Convert JSON Array to XML - Groovy

Tags: json, xml, groovy, soapui

Hi I'm new to REST and JSON response. I have done SOAP based work before. I am trying to convert a JSON Array body into XML. Could someone please guide me with the kind of code to use in Groovy? I have seen several answers out there but I'm not able to modify them aptly for the JSON body I have. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Sample JSON:

```
[
      {
      "field": "GULP",
      "baseDT":       {
         "name": "HaveAGulp",
         "descriptionTx": "Gulp the water",
         "flow":          {
            "beginDate": "2016-08-31",
            "endDate": "9999-12-31"
         },
         "check":          {
            "createUserId": "GULPUSER",
            "createTs": "2016-08-30 11:08:56.985204",
            "lastModifiedUser": "GULPUSER",
            "lastModifiedTs": "2016-08-30 11:08:56.985204"
         }
      }
   },
      {
      "field": "HELP",
      "baseDT":       {
         "name": "HelpSomeone",
         "descriptionTx": "Help Help Help",
         "flow":          {
            "beginDate": "2016-08-31",
            "endDate": "9999-12-31"
         },
         "check":          {
            "createUserId": "HELPUSER",
            "createTs": "2016-08-30 11:08:56.985204",
            "lastModifiedUser": "HELPUSER",
            "lastModifiedTs": "2016-08-30 11:08:56.985204"
         }
      }
   }
]
```

Expecting XML: Since there are no node names from the JSON we still want to have serialized index for each set within the JSON array.

```
<jsonAsXML>
    <0>
        <field>GULP</field>
        <baseDT>
            <name>HaveAGulp</name>
            <descriptionTx>Gulp the water</descriptionTx>
            <flow>
                <beginDate>2016-08-31</beginDate>
                <endDate>9999-12-31</endDate>
            </flow>
            <check>
                <createUserId>HELPUSER</createUserId>
                <createTs>2016-08-30 11:08:56.985204</createTs>
                <lastModifiedUser>HELPUSER</lastModifiedUser>
                <lastModifiedTs>2016-08-30 11:08:56.985204</lastModifiedTs>
        </baseDT>
    </0>
    <1>...
    </1>
</jsonAsXML>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937254/convert-json-to-xml-using-groovy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [`JsonSlurper`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html) to get the *JSON* to traverse it, and [`Markupbuilder`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/xml/MarkupBuilder.html) to save it as a *XML*. This is only an example and doesn't take in account all possibilities since I'm supposing as you show in your example that your *JSON* root is always an `Array`.

```
import groovy.json.*
import groovy.xml.*

def json = '''[
      {
      "field": "GULP",
      "baseDT":       {
         "name": "HaveAGulp",
         "descriptionTx": "Gulp the water",
         "flow":          {
            "beginDate": "2016-08-31",
            "endDate": "9999-12-31"
         },
         "check":          {
            "createUserId": "GULPUSER",
            "createTs": "2016-08-30 11:08:56.985204",
            "lastModifiedUser": "GULPUSER",
            "lastModifiedTs": "2016-08-30 11:08:56.985204"
         }
      }
   }
]'''

// parse your json
def slurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)

// recursive helper to traverse the structure
def helper(map){
    return {
        map.each{ k,v ->
            println "$k $v"
            if(v instanceof Map){
                "$k" helper(v)
            }else if(v instanceof List){
                v.each{ element ->
                    "$k" helper(element)
                }
            }else{
                "$k"("$v")
            }
        }
    }
}

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter()
new MarkupBuilder(writer).jsonAsXml {
    // for each element in the json array
    slurper.eachWithIndex { content, index ->
        "$index"( helper(content) )
    }
}

println writer.toString()
```

This code returns your *JSON* transformed in the follow *XML*:

```
<jsonAsXml>
  <0>
    <baseDT>
      <check>
        <createTs>2016-08-30 11:08:56.985204</createTs>
        <createUserId>GULPUSER</createUserId>
        <lastModifiedTs>2016-08-30 11:08:56.985204</lastModifiedTs>
        <lastModifiedUser>GULPUSER</lastModifiedUser>
      </check>
      <descriptionTx>Gulp the water</descriptionTx>
      <flow>
        <beginDate>2016-08-31</beginDate>
        <endDate>9999-12-31</endDate>
      </flow>
      <name>HaveAGulp</name>
    </baseDT>
    <field>GULP</field>
  </0>
</jsonAsXml>
```

**NOTE**: The *XML* normally has an *xsd* however *JSON* is a more "free" format, so in it's spec attribute order is not mandatory due to this `JsonSlurper` returns a `groovy.json.internal.LazyMap` which don't care about. This is why the *XML* elements are not in the order you expect.

Comment: Very nice @albciff.

Comment: @albciff Thank you so much for your response, really appreciate it! This is working for me just fine. I think the order is still okay as I will be comparing this with response from a JDBC Request test step. I will probably order the objects in both the XMLs and compare them.

Comment: @ssc you're welcome :), to compare then both xml this could be an easy and good option http://stackoverflow.com/a/13730729/1218618